# Placing a floating div next to another

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner and would like to get some help and see where I'm making a mistake. I would like it so the text "?" is left aligned next to the text below it. Thanks in advance.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="clear"></div>                   
<div style="text-align:center;margin:10px 0 20px 0;">
<!---<img src="/images/test.jpg"/>-->
<a class="tooltip" title="Search in the box">?</a> 
<div style="font-size:16px">Choose Your Carrier:</div>
```

Comment: Please JSFiddle that fragment!

Comment: Change your mark-up and you will get it done! FOR Eg. `<span>`s are inline handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `<a class="tooltip" title="Search in the box">?</a>`

into the div

```
<div style="font-size:16px; word-wrap: none;">Choose Your Carrier: <a class="tooltip" title="Search in the box">?</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `display: inline` both elements (a and div).